# Can $||f||_p$ tend toward infinity arbitrarily slowly?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Suppose $f$ is Lebesgue measurable on $(0,1)$, and not essentially bounded.  Can $||f||_p$ tend to $\infty$ arbitrarily slowly?

I am really lost on this problem. I assume the answer is that it can  tend to $\infty$ arbitrarlily slowly but showing that is really difficult. I have tried letting $f=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k 1_{E_k}$ where $E_i$ is a disjoint collection of subset of $(0,1)$, and working from there but I am at a loss here. Any guidence?

---

Arbitrarilly slowly-  We say that $||f||_p$ tend to infinity arbitrarilly slowly if for every positive function $\Phi(p)$ on $(0,\infty)$ with $\lim_{p\to \infty}\Phi(p)=\infty$ there exists a function $f$ on $(0,1)$  such that $||f||_p\leq \Phi(p)$ for all large enough $p$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by arbitrarily slowly?

Comment: @Reveillark I put in a definition in the post

Comment: The question was asked at least twice before by others (but remains unanswered) at [Exercise 3.9 in rudin's real and complex analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542537/exercise-3-9-in-rudins-real-and-complex-analysis) and [Can $\|f\|_p \to \infty$ arbitrarily slowly? (Looking for hints.)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955824/can-f-p-to-infty-arbitrarily-slowly-looking-for-hints).

Comment: @Weaam Thank you for the link!!! It fully answers my question.